# How to properly include global variables and update them in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

Assuming my application has a variable "globalFruits" that keeps track of all the "Fruits" within my app.

var globalFruits = {}

globalFruits['Pear'] = {name:'Pear', color:'green'};
globalFruits['Apple'] = {name:'Apple', color:'Blue'};

How should this global variable be included in my AngularJS application such that I can have directives or scopes that can call it and check on its state? Or is that not the AngularJS way?

Comment: if it is global, you can call it from angular?

Comment: I know how to declare it without using angularJS, but I wnated to know if there was some proper convention to do that. Especially when say, I want globalFruits to be able to affect say, certain UI elements on multiple aspects of my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a **[value](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide#value)** for your module :

```
app.value('globalFruits', {
  Pear: {name:'Pear', color:'green'},
  Apple: {name:'Apple', color:'Blue'}
);
```

Then, you can inject this value when you want to work with it :

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'globalFruits', function($scope, globalFruits) {
  $scope.globalFruits = globalFruits;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [$rootScope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope) model which can be used for things like that

```
app.config(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.fruits = [
        {name:'Pear', color:'green'},
        {name:'Apple', color:'Blue'}
    ];
}]);
```

Which you can use as usual in your HTML view:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">{{ fruit.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

To debug scope variables in your browser, you may want to install and use [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk) extension for Google Chrome.

**More info**: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope